# How to identify data does not exists in a variable in R

Tags: r

I have my dataset like

```
v1 v2  
1  
3  small  
5  medium  
8  
2  high
```

How would I check for these missing values in `v2` column?
`is.null` is giving `FALSE` if i check like `is.null(data$v2)`

Comment: are they blank strings - `""` ?

Comment: yes they are blank strings and they are factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What data type is the `v2` column, a factor or character vector? What values do the "missing" values take, just empty strings or do white spaces count as empty as well?

This will work if they are empty strings:

```
data$v2 == ""
```

If white spaces are counted as missing, then this should work:

```
trimws(data$v2) == ""
```

Comment: @rahul When someone helps you on StackOverflow, it is customary to "thank" that person by marking the answer as "accepted" (the check mark to the left), and/or vote up the answer by pressing the arrow pointing up. This way, when other people have the same question as you, they'll find the answer quicker, and those writing answers get some credit. See http://stackoverflow.com/tour for more info.

Comment: HI Fredrick,Sorry i din't mean to offend you..I am new to stackoverflow.I didn't know the process..Thanks for the help.I did try to upvote but my vote is not showing.may be i dont have that much reputation.So i marked it as accepted.

Comment: @rahul No worries, just wanted to let you know. And yes, you need a certain amount of reputation to do certain things. Thanks for the accept, I'm glad I could help you.